# Upper bounds for solutions to a Pell-like equation

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $N$ be a fixed positive integer that is not a square and $m$ be any nonzero integer. Let $x$ and $y$ be positive integers that solve $$x^2 - N y^2 = m^2$$ with $x + y$ minimal (in light of the comment below, please take $m$ to be 1).

What is known about upper bounds for $x$ and $y$?

Comment: They are at most $m$ times the fundamental solution to $x^2-Ny^2=1$, and in general we cannot do better.

Comment: Perhaps this is a duplicate of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/252879/upper-bounds-for-regulators-of-real-quadratic-fields

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/229439/upper-bound-on-answer-for-pell-equation

Answer (score 1):

There is a positive constant $c_1$ such that there are values of $N$ with $\log(x+y\sqrt N)>c_1\log\sqrt N$. See, e.g., Yamamoto, Real quadratic number fields with large fundamental units, or [this](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/students/reu/units.pdf) expository essay.

The Yamamoto [paper](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ojm/1200693242) is also available online.

Comment: So this is a form of lower bound.  Do the papers talk about upper bounds?  Gerhard "Upper Bounds Useful For Planning" Paseman, 2016.12.10.

Comment: Oops. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: Yamamoto cites the result, $h\log(x+y\sqrt N)<\sqrt N(\log\sqrt N+1)$ where $h$ is the class number, from which it follows that $\log(x+y\sqrt N)<\sqrt N(\log\sqrt N+1)$. The citation is L K Hua, On the least solution of Pell's equation, Bull Amer Math Soc 48 (1942) 731-735. The Hua paper is available at https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183504769

Comment: There's a nice paper by Lenstra, https://www.uni-oldenburg.de/fileadmin/user_upload/mathe/personen/steffen.mueller/01lenstra.pdf